# How to start with PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, ide

I am newbie in PHP. I have successfully installed PHP on Ubuntu, now I want start my first program. I am using gPHPEdit as IDE.
Where should I save .php files that I create? And how to run/test them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pick up a book or start following some good tutorials on the web.
If you are just scripting using php, you can save them anywhere and run the php on the terminal using the php command line interpreter.
If you are trying write web scripts (and I think you are), you need to install and configure a web server (typically apache) and save your scripts in the server's document root (typically /var/www). Also, I highly recommend you to read up a little about servers and HTTP and figure out how all this works on the inside before learning to building websites in php.

Comment: Thanks for reply,Is there any good book or link which i should read before starting with php? I have folder Server's document root(/var/www) but i am not able to save/paste files there, do u have any idea about this?

Comment: sudo cp myfile.php /var/www/myfile.php

Comment: in unix systems, different users have permissions to edit and write different directories(folders). the /var/www directory is writable by root and not the normal user(by default). You can prefix commands with sudo and enter your root password (dont think ubuntu has any by default) to execute commands in root scope. If you are not using the terminal for all this stuff, you should learn some basic terminal commands.

Comment: Thanks all for your reply. It helped me alot

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have `LAMP` installed.  Do a `sudo tasksel` and select lamp then hit enter,  its gotta be the most simple *amp install ever made.  Its a good idea to install phpmyadmin: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`.   After that just copy the files to `/var/www/` and then they will show up on `http://localhost`.    I recommended using Eclipse PDT or the Netbeans build for PHP.

Comment: "its gotta be the most simple *amp install ever made." +1 - I agree.  I usually do `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot save or copy to var/www/html, to run your php scripts on your browser. If you are using Ubuntu 14.04. 
I followed these steps and it worked for me.

1. Execute `sudo su` on the terminal.
2. Enter your password
3. Execute `sudo subl /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` on your terminal to open this file. Note you can change the subl to any text editor to open the file e.g `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf.`
4. Change `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to `/home/user/yoursubdir`
5. Save the file and close it.
6. Execute `sudo subl /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` on your terminal to open this file.
7. Add the following to end of the file

   ```
   <Directory /home/user/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
8. Save and Close the file.
9. Execute `sudo service apache2 restart`
10. Go to your browser, type the URL of your script e.g  `127.0.1.1/directory/document.php.`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

remove the index.html file from `/var/www/`

```
$ sudo rm index.html
```

create a new php file there:

```
$ sudo gedit /var/www/index.php
```

write in it:

```
<?php
print_r(phpinfo());
?>
```

Restart your Apache2 Server :

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

OR

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apace2 restart
```

and point to yout localhost and /index.php

if err arises visit : http://www.allaboutlinux.eu/how-to-run-php-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

this is an easy way to test your files in php.

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

then you can go to your browser and enter `localhost:8000/myfile.php`.